# Cloudfront - Custom origin 403 Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have 3 CloudFront distributions, e.g. ONE, TWO and THREE.

- ONE has a behaviour to forward requests to custom origin TWO.
- TWO has a behaviour to forward requests to custom origin THREE.
- THREE forwards requests to API Gateway.

When I make a request directly to TWO, the response is successful (e.g. https://TWO.cloudfront.net/api/values).
However, When I request through ONE I receive a 403 (e.g. https://ONE.cloudfront.net/api/values).

Comment: what kind of request GET/POST ? Does it have a body?

Comment: We are using a get request without a body

Comment: every request travels through CloudFront gets adds by via header e,g: via: 1026589cc7887e7a0dc7827b4example.cloudfront.net and when cloudfront sees 3 via headers as cloudfront.net, it considers it as loop and block the request with 403.

Comment: @JamesDean - thanks for your comment. This makes sense. When we compare the request logs the only differences between ONE and TWO are the via and x-forwarded-for headers. We never get logs from CloudFront distribution THREE when we pass through ONE, which is strange. I would assume this is the distribution that is returning the 403. Do you know a workaround for this? I believe that the via headers are read-only.

Comment: Do you have any use case for 3 cloudfront distributions?

Comment: Yes, we are creating a micro frontend which resides between 2 distributions. ONE is the container application, TWO is the micro frontend, THREE is an API.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. I'm also getting a 403. Curious what your work around ended up being